# How to shorten a function in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to insert `skill` in MySQL table called `skills`.

I have `skills` as `param[:skills] = "Lorem, Ipsum, Is, A, Dummy, Text"`

I want to insert them to MySql DB.

The way I use is:

```
def skill_to_add
    skills = params[:skills].split(',')
    skills.each do |s|
        find_skill = Skill.find_by(:skill => s)
        if find_skill
            find_skill.update(:skill_count => find_skill.skill_count + 1)
        else
            Skill.create(:skill => s, :skill_count => 1) 
        end
    end
end
```

What will be the clean way to do this thing?

Comment: I dont' think you could do `find_skill.update(:skill_count = find_skill+1)`. Should not be possible to add `Integer` to `Skill`.

Comment: What's your expected result, i.e. how should the table look like afterwards?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Sorry it was some typo. check now.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss Thanks for the link reference.

Comment: @Stefan Skill.all to list all the skills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `find_or_create_by` ([see the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)):

```
skills.each do |skill_name|
  skill = Skill.find_or_create_by(skill: skill_name)
  skill.increment(:skill_count)
  skill.save
end
```

**NOTE**: you need to set the column to an integer column with 0 as default value, to work properly.

I would also suggest that you rename your Skill model attributes to:

```
Skill
  -> name
  -> count
```

often it's pretty redundant to use `Skill.skill_count`.

Sideote: In the line of

```
skills = params[:skills].split(',')
```

you are going to create skills with spaces in the name, why?

```
skills = 'Lorem, Ipsum, Is, A, Dummy, Text'.split(',')
skills # => ['Lorem', ' Ipsum', ' Is', ' A', ' Dummy', ' Text']
```

I think you want to [strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-strip) the splitted values:

```
skills = params[:skills].split(',').map(&:strip)
```

Comment: Thank you. The perfect answer.